# Using Google Calendar API with Angular 7 ... typescript types, libraries, implementation

Tags: angular, google-calendar-api

Has anyone implemented a working google calendar API with Angular (2+) that you could share? Trying to get this going and finding it rather complex.

Comment: Yes, I have a sample code in the github of the complete integration of Google Calendar and other Google API's like Drive and Youtube. Just check this [link](https://github.com/Fresiamay17/google-api-integration-app) for details.

Comment: @jess How do you make it work in a local environmnment for testing? I keep getting Google errors and an unable to add localhost:2612 as a Google permitted url... How did you do it? Something to do with whitelisting ...?

Comment: What kind of error you encountered? I just run the code in localhost:4200. Reminder that before you will run the code, you must first have the generated credentials.json from the Google Console and be sure that the Calendar API was enabled.

Answer (score -1):

```
const google = `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?text=${name}&ctz=${timezoneName}&dates=${startTime}z/${endTime}z&details=${description}&location=${location}&trp=false`;
    this.globalObjectService.getWindow().open(google, '_blank');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.